# Can't get FFI to work. Function in DLL not found

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dll, ffi

I have a simple DLL:

here the .h file:

```
#ifdef WIN32PROJECT3_EXPORTS
#define WIN32PROJECT3_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WIN32PROJECT3_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the Win32Project3.dll
class WIN32PROJECT3_API CWin32Project3 {
public:
    CWin32Project3(void);
    // TODO: add your methods here.
};

extern WIN32PROJECT3_API int nWin32Project3;

WIN32PROJECT3_API int pippo(int value);
```

here the .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project3.h"
WIN32PROJECT3_API int nWin32Project3=0;

// This is an example of an exported function.

WIN32PROJECT3_API int pippo(int value)
{
    return 42 * value;
}

// This is the constructor of a class that has been exported.
// see Win32Project3.h for the class definition
CWin32Project3::CWin32Project3()
{
    return;
}
```

That's the Ruby side:

```
require 'ffi'

 module TestModule
    extend FFI::Library
    ffi_lib 'Win32Project3'
    attach_function :pippo, [:int], :int
  end
```

Ruby doesn't find the exported `int pippo(int value)` method. It successfully loads the DLL but cannot find the function. The error is quite self explanatory but doesn't tell what's causing it.

That's the actual error string from the ruby console:

Function 'pippo' not found in [Win32Project3] (FFI:NotFoundError)

Comment: You probably need to wrap you function in `extern C` in order to avoid name mangling.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: yeah AFAIK FFI can't call C++ at all today...swig maybe...

Comment: @rogerdpack: we are talking about a precompiled DLL. The used programming languages is not an issue

Comment: your method "pippo" was probably compiled using a c++ compiler, without being wrapped by an "extern C {}" block, which mangles names...

Comment: what was the end fix?

Comment: I had to ''extern C'' the function to avoid name mangling by the C++ compiler. That's why ffi didnt found the symbol